# Why is LESS telling me there's something missing?

Tags: css, less

This is my first project with less and i thought i'd been following a tutorial word for word however when i go to compile with lessc i get the following error:

```
ParseError: Unrecognised input. Possibly missing something in C:\Path\to\file.less on line 1226, column 2:
1225   margin-top: @footer-text-margin-top;
1226 }
```

below is the full section of that code.

```
.footer-text {
  margin: @footer-text-margin;
  margin-top: @footer-text-margin-top;
}
```

I keep getting this no matter what the code itself is, it's always on the last line and i get no other errors. Have i missed an escape ? Or do I need to import something into the .less file ??

edit: this doesn't just happen using lessc, I get the same error using LESS2SS in the browser and WinLess on Windows. It works as raw CSS which is what makes me think I've missed something to do with LESS itself.

Comment: I tried on http://lesstester.com/ and this works. Try to find error somewhere above this lines. Or recheck your variables

Comment: Maybe the error is about a line above.

Comment: If it's "always on the last line" it looks like most likely some missing `}`, `)`, `*/` or other block terminating symbols (the compiler tries to detect those as earlier as possible but it's not always can be done because of nesting and similar stuff). Try to incrementally (from bottom to top) disable large parts of you code to find when the error disappears (or put somewhere the whole file so we could test it too).

Answer (score 0):

`margin-top` is actually declared two times. This is enough:

```
.footer-text {
  margin: @footer-text-margin;
}
```

For **example**: `margin: 10px 15px 16px 17px`, your margin-top is already defined as the first value. It actually works like `margin: top right bottom left;`

The first step would be to remove this `margin-top` line. If the message is still there but focusing the line before, the comment of *@seven-phases-max* about missing `}`, `)`, `*/` is clearly right.

Otherwise it's about the var declaration IMO.

Good Luck'

Comment: I need an explanation about the `-1`? How my message is not accurate? The reason of this issue could be actually this.

Comment: It simply does not answer the Q. If you think the code should be written in a different way - OK - but post it as comment since this definitely does not help OP to find why he's getting his error.

Comment: @seven-phases-max It's not about way to be written, it's actually about solving his problem. The first step would be to remove this line. If the message is still there but focusing the line before, your comment about missing `}`, `)`, `*/` is clearly right. Otherwise it's about the `var` declaration. But I got your point. Editing the post to develop this.

Comment: Well, the code in the OP snippet is absolutely valid (in CSS we obviously  may repeat any property infinitely). So, no, removing just last line of it barely coulld help (not a big deal to remove the downvote though if you care of these things too much).

Comment: @seven-phases-max I don't, tbh. Even if my first message could be interpreted like this, I just try to still understand how things work around here and that's also why I edited my answer to make it more accurate, or to try at least. Leave this `-1` if you still consider that this answer is not appropriate with the OP's question. I'm not here for the points and badges, but to help and being helped.

Comment: @RedBreast: Actually even from a pure CSS perspective the extra declaration is not wrong. I have seen quite a lot of cases where people tend to use `margin: 4px` followed by `margin-top: 6px` as a means to override just the `margin-top` alone. May not be the best way of coding but certainly not wrong either.